# Calculate the Work in a cylinder tank, through integral

Tags: calculus

"A vertical cylindrical tank has a height of 9 m and a diameter of 6 m. The tank is full of oil that weighs 8042 N per cubic meter. The pumping is done from the top of the tank. How much work is required to pump all the oil to the rim of the tank?"

We are asked to calculate the work though integral.
I tried to do so, but we need the limits of variable x so that to calculate the integral of the force.
I would appreciate for your guidance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Take any infinitely thin layer of oil. Its mass $dm$ will be in proportion to $dy$. Once you find $dm$, you need to find work done against gravity to take it up. Let me know where you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much. So We calculate the integral of 8042*(9-y) with 0≤y≤9? Do We have to use the diameter as well?

Comment: Yes you have to use the diameter as well but it is a constant for the integral.

Comment: You helped me a lot, Thank you very much. Have a nice Day!

Comment: Thank you very much.I calculated the integral of: pi*(r^2)*8042*(9-y), with 0≤y≤9 Is it correct?

Comment: Were you able to complete it?

Comment: Yes it should be $8042 \cdot \pi \cdot 3^2 \cdot \int_0^{9} (9-y) dy$

Comment: Thank you very much, be well and safe!

Answer (score 0):

Your integral should be with respect to $y$, with $0 \leq y \leq 9$. Then take a horizontal slab of the tank, and calculate the weight of the slab of oil. The thickness of the slab will be $\Delta y$, and because you have a cylindrical tank, the radius does not change. This simplifies the calculation of the weight of the slab. Then multiply this weight by $(9 - y)$, which is the distance the slab must be moved to the top of the tank (remember work = force times distance). Then integrate this quantity, with $\Delta y$ replaced by $dy$.